# Why do we say "study window" not "study's window"?

Tags: possessives, attributive-nouns

Do you know *why* we say **study window** not **study's window** although we mean the window which belongs to a study(room)? I want to know the *reason*.

Comment: Do you mean like a one-way mirror in an observation room? **Study window** can also mean the length of time one can study for exams.

Comment: I haven't heard any *study window* ever. You could say room's window.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of a [noun adjunct](http://www.englishcorner.vacau.com/grammar/rules/nounadj.html)? That's when we use a noun (like *study*) to modify another noun (like *window*), to indicate what kind of a thing it is.  We do this a lot in English.  For example: wrist watch, horse race, phone book, kitchen sink, etc.

Comment: @Andrew - I wouldn't really call it an *abbreviation*; it's a different construction, not an abbreviation.  The question about possessives specifically says "why *attribute declaration* and not *attribute's declaration*", just as this one says "why *study window* and not *study's window*", so I think it's the same basic question.

Comment: @stangdon, I agree with you. The question is initially about the possessive *s*.

Comment: @stangdon I removed my comment and edited my answer to include your link to the page on noun adjuncts.  Are these examples of possessives, though?  The page seems to treat them like ordinary *adjectives*.  I think it's more likely OP is not familiar with this structure and so is confused with possessives.

Comment: Study window, bedroom window, office window, they are all the same, noun adjuncts.

Answer (score 0):

As stangdon points out in his comment this is called a ["noun adjunct"](http://www.englishcorner.vacau.com/grammar/rules/nounadj.html). It is very common and not limited to household objects.  The first noun acts like an *adjective* to modify the second noun.

I think that you understand that "study window" actually means "the window in the study", so perhaps you're just not familiar with the structure: "rose bush", "wrist watch", "apple sauce", etc.

Other examples:

> Please be sure to close the **cellar door** (door to the cellar) so the cat doesn't go down.
>
> I bought a new **hallway mirror** (mirror that hangs in the hallway) at a sale last week.
>
> The **kitchen sink** (sink in the kitchen) is clogged again.

Answer (score 0):

I probably read this completely the wrong way but: [LINK](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/window)

a :  an interval of time within which a rocket or spacecraft must be launched to accomplish a particular mission

b :  an interval of time during which certain conditions or an opportunity exists

I saw it as the interval of time available for study.

So I wonder if the OP read it the wrong way.